# When does the Fourier transform of a measure decay?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\Bbb R^d$.

It is well known that $\mu= |f|dx$ with $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ then its Fourier transform satisfies
$$\widehat{\mu}(\xi)\to0,\qquad \xi\to\infty.$$

However if $\mu=\delta_0$ is the Dirac impulse then
$$\widehat{\mu}(\xi)=cste.$$

Under which condition on $\mu$ do we have $\widehat{\mu}(\xi)\to0,\quad \xi\to\infty$?

Comment: For the question in the title, the keyword is the Rajchman measure.

Comment: I don't think that this question deserved a downvote. It may well be that there is an answer in the literature, but I don't know any and find the question interesting.

Comment: Please see https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1984-15198-X